# Subtitle problem in m2ts video file

Tags: windows-7, video, vlc-media-player, m2ts

In my Windows 7 Ultimate (32 bit) OS, VLC Media Player 1.1.5 can play m2ts video file. But when I load an srt file, VLC stops playing the video file. No message is shown.

I don't use any other video player. I tried with Windows Media Player but not sure how to load subtitle file in it.

Is there any solution for VLC for the problem?

Comment: See this...http://www.afterdawn.com/guides/archive/how_to_play_m2ts_files.cfm

Comment: nothing useful in that website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [known VLC bug](http://trac.videolan.org/vlc/ticket/3075).

The bug was open for 2+ years and has been recently closed. To the date of writing (Nov/06) the fix has not yet been released in any VLC version.